# Maven2: change execution during reactor build

Tags: deployment, module, maven-2

I have a multi-module project (5 modules) running on maven2 and I'd like to do the following:

1. Run MVN clean deploy in 3 modules
2. run MVN clean test in 2 modules.

Is there a way to accomplish this with a single Maven execution?

The goal is to avoid deploying modules which aren't needed by any other projects making the build faster.

Comment: You know that deploy lifecycle includes the test lifecycle phase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control which projects would skip deploy or test build lifecycle phases using profiles and set skip property in maven [deploy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#skip) and [surefire](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skip) plugins in those profiles in individual project.

However, deploy phase is the latest phase in the build lifecycle, so you will have to use something like [Maven Invoker Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html) to spawn another Maven process.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know the skip parameter of deploy.

Didn understand the last part of your comment tough: I'm planning to declare the deploy plugin bound to a variable and just change its value to true whenever necessary.

Comment: The "mvn deploy" command is actually invokes the deploy lifecycle phase to which deploy:deploy goal is bound by default, but you could invoke deploy:deploy directly.